# I bought a domain name that had previously registered for Google Apps for your Domain. Is there any way to use Google Apps for this new account?

Tags: google-apps, domain-name

I bought a domain name without realizing it was from a business that dropped it in 2010. When I tried to sign up for Google Apps for your Domain, it wouldn't let me since they had previously signed up. Is there a procedure by which I could get Google to give me service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Google you can go reset the admin password for purchased domains that have previously used Google Apps:

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=80610